# How to use push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I want to enable push notification so that when i post something on my blog it would appear on the user's device and show the title of the post. I have been researching for a week now and i still could not find a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For new browsers you can use websocket from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets and for older browsers you can use long-polling.

Answer (score 1):

For receiving the Apple push notification on your device, your mobile app needs to register for Apple Push Notification Service(APNS) from the device. To see how push notification works in iOS check the below link.
[How Push Notification works in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: i followed through that. But it says that my device token would be shown in the log.  But it didn't appear

Comment: You have to use an iOS device to test the push notification functionality. It wont work with simulator.

Comment: i did run it on my phone

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to develop a client app for the client device. Specifically for OS X Safari there are [Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) available.